# Oracle driver in maven project

Tags: java, oracle, maven, glassfish

I have a maven project with c3p0 configured and the driver responsible to connect to the database is not found when running the project. I put the jar of oracle driver `ojdbc6.jar` in lib/ext folder on glassfish but nothing changed. I have another project on the same glassfish that connect to the same database by this driver and everything works fine.

I get the following error:

```
Info:   HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
Info:   HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.10.Final}
Info:   HHH000205: Loaded properties from resource hibernate.properties: {hibernate.search.default.directory_provider=filesystem, hibernate.search.worker.execution=async, hibernate.c3p0.max_statements=50, hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer=false, hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=1000, hibernate.c3p0.timeout=90, hibernate.generate_statistics=false, hibernate.search.analyzer=org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.KeywordAnalyzer, hibernate.auto_close_session=true, hibernate.c3p0.min_size=5, hibernate.connection.pool_size=5, hibernate.search.worker.batch_size=100, app.search.index.basedir=target/index, hibernate.search.default.exclusive_index_use=true, app.search.enable.false=false, hibernate.search.lucene_version=LUCENE_35, hibernate.c3p0.max_size=20, hibernate.c3p0.debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces=true, hibernate.connection.provider_class=org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider, hibernate.c3p0.unreturnedConnectionTimeout=90, hibernate.search.default.locking_strategy=simple}
Info:   HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Info:   HHH000044: Configuring from URL: file:/C:/.../target/classes/hibernate.cfg.xml
Info:   HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
Info:   HHH000130: Instantiating explicit connection provider: org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider
Info:   HHH010002: C3P0 using driver: null at URL: null
Info:   HHH000046: Connection properties: {}
Info:   HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
WARN:   HHH000148: No JDBC Driver class was specified by property hibernate.connection.driver_class
Info:   WARN  2017-11-20-11:39:23,779 BasicResourcePool.run(1851) | com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@3113673d -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.getProtocol(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:524)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.knownURL(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:493)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.acceptsURL(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:307)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:262)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.driver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:240)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:131)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:156)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:145)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:200)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1086)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1073)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:648)
```

Any idea to solve this?

Comment: Looks like a misconfiguration in your `persistence.xml`, did you check if its equal to the one in the working project?

Comment: Hi, I don't have a persistence.xml in the second project...

Comment: But I guess you have configured your DataSource somewhere...